# Broken cursor in InkCanvas (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, virtual-machine, mouse-cursor, inkcanvas

I created simple application with drawing canvas (InkCanvas) in C# WPF, which look like this (normal):
[image]

But when I run same application on VirtualMachine (Windows 10 in VirtualBox), cursor looks broken:
[image]

If I change appearance of cursor in Windows on VirtualMachine, broken cursor changes too:

[image]

The only similar case that resembles my problem, that I found, is this:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/mouse-pointer-corrupt/m-p/10300169

I updated Windows to latest version, but that didn't helped.

Would anyone know what the problem might be (drivers or some specific corrupted files in Windows)?

**Edit 1**:
Same in "Snip & Sketch" application - only as highlighter:
[image]

Comment: It could possibly be your system's display adapter isn't good enough to display your VM's desktop interface. I'd try lowering the resolution of your VM or even testing other apps on your VM that have inking, such as Paint or "Snip & Sketch", and see if they also has mouse visualization problems.

Comment: @TamBui I tried same VM on different PCs and broken cursor appears everywhere regardless of the computer on which the VM is running. Cursor is OK in "Paint", but broken as highlighter in "Snip & Sketch" (viz. Edit). Changing resolution or scaling didnt help either.